# Must JTextField.getText and JButton.addActionListener be Executed on the EDT

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Should I assume that the following program is wrong because lines x and y (at the very end of the main method) are not executed on the EDT?

```
public class Temp
{
    private static JButton     button;
    private static JTextField  text;
    
    private static void showGUI()
    {
        JFrame  frame       = new JFrame();
        JPanel  contentPane = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton( "Push Me" );
        text = new JTextField( "I am the walrus" );
        contentPane.add( button );
        contentPane.add( text );
        frame.setContentPane( contentPane );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait( () -> showGUI() );
        /* x */ System.out.println( text.getText() );
        /* y */ button.addActionListener( System.out::println );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, you should**.

Lines x and y are indeed not executed on the EDT, which could lead to potential issues in Swing applications.

The `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` method you're using in the `main` method is used to execute the `showGUI()` method on the EDT, which is correct. However, the subsequent lines x and y are executed on the main thread, which could lead to synchronization problems and unexpected behavior.

To ensure that lines x and y are executed on the EDT, you should wrap them in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` call as well.

This way:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait( () -> showGUI() );
    
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> {
        /* x */ System.out.println( text.getText() );
        /* y */ button.addActionListener( System.out::println );
    });
}
```

[Check this out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)